# Spark fillNa not replacing the null value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following dataset and its contain some null values, need to replace the null value using fillna in spark.

DataFrame:

```
df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header‌​","true").load("/sam‌​ple.csv")

>>> df.printSchema();
root
 |-- Age: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Height: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)

>>> df.show()
+---+------+-----+
|Age|Height| Name|
+---+------+-----+
| 10|    80|Alice|
|  5|  null|  Bob|
| 50|  null|  Tom|
| 50|  null| null|
+---+------+-----+

>>> df.na.fill(10).show()
```

when i'll  give the na values it dosen't changed the same dataframe appeared again.

```
+---+------+-----+
|Age|Height| Name|
+---+------+-----+
| 10|    80|Alice|
|  5|  null|  Bob|
| 50|  null|  Tom|
| 50|  null| null|
+---+------+-----+
```

tried create a new dataframe and store the fill values in dataframe but the result showing like unchanged.

```
>>> df2 = df.na.fill(10)
```

how to replace the null values? please give me the possible ways by using fill na.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is there any rules for replacement ? e.g Is replacing nulls in the Height column different than the Name column ?

Comment: In my case the null value not replaced, if the rule applied or else not specified the rule. the basic fill operation not working properly. checked with the different datasets.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It seems that your `Height` column is not numeric. When you call `df.na.fill(10)` spark replaces only nulls with column that match type of `10`, which are numeric columns.

If `Height` column need to be string, you can try `df.na.fill('10').show()`, otherwise casting to `IntegerType()` is neccessary.

Comment: `df.na.fill('10').show()` I'll tried with this code, but not working properly. How can i casting to `int` any examples?

Comment: here you can find documentation for casting dataframe columns: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.cast - the `'int'` type or `IntegerType()` is valid type for storing numbers.

Comment: @Marisuz thanks for the info it's working. now i have a doubt can i directly fill the string like `df.na.fill("sample")` like this, instead of giving condition `df.na.fill({'age': 50, 'name': 'sample'})`.

Comment: Yes, sure. Take a look at documentation.

Comment: I'll checked with the documentation but i don't found anything for my case. instead of conditions there is any possible ways?

Comment: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.fillna

Answer (score 14):

You can also provide a specific default value for each column if you prefer.

```
df.na.fill({'Height': '10', 'Name': 'Bob'})
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Mariusz answer, here is the exact code to cast and fill NA values:

```py
   from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
   from pyspark.sql.functions import col

   df = df.withColumn("Height", col("Height").cast(IntegerType()))
   df2 = df.na.fill(value=10, subset=["Height"])
```

maybe the simpler solution would've been to give a string value, if you don't care about the column type:

```
   df2 = df.na.fill(value="10", subset=["Height"])
```