# PySpark: fillna function not working even after casting type

Tags: pyspark, fillna

I have a dataframe with two columns which looks like the following:

```
+----+-----+
|type|class|
+----+-----+
|    |    0|
|    |    0|
|    |    0|
|    |    0|
|    |    0|
+----+-----+
only showing top 5 rows
```

I'm trying to fill in empty values with some arbitrary string so I did the following:

```
df = df.fillna({'type': 'Empty'})
```

Which again shows me the same results:

```
+----+-----+
|type|class|
+----+-----+
|    |    0|
|    |    0|
|    |    0|
|    |    0|
|    |    0|
+----+-----+
only showing top 5 rows
```

So I searched around and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40395932/spark-fillna-not-replacing-the-null-value) on stackoverflow suggesting mismatched types might cause this issue so I did:

```
df = df.withColumn("type", df["type"].cast("string"))
df = df.fillna({'type': 'Empty'})
```

I have to mention that the original dataframe has the following schema:

```
StructField(type,StringType,true)
```

Also, I have tried:

```
df = df.withColumn("type", when(df["type"] != '', df["type"]).otherwise('Empty'))
```

Which works just fine. Am I missing something here? Is `fillna` not what I'm looking for?

Comment: `fillna` is used to replace **null** values and you have `''` (empty string) in your type column, which is why it's not working.

Comment: @Psidom what would I use for empty strings then? Is there a built in function that could handle empty strings?

Comment: You can use `na.replace` method for this purpose. Made an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fillna` is used to replace null values and you have `''` (empty string) in your type column; To replace a general value you can use `na.replace` method:

```
df.na.replace('', 'Empty String', 'type').show()
+------------+-----+
|        type|class|
+------------+-----+
|Empty String|    0|
|Empty String|    0|
+------------+-----+
```

Or:

```
df.na.replace({'': 'Empty String'}, 'type').show()
+------------+-----+
|        type|class|
+------------+-----+
|Empty String|    0|
|Empty String|    0|
+------------+-----+
```

Or use `DataFrame.replace` method which is an alias for `na.replace`:

```
df.replace('', 'Empty String', 'type').show()
+------------+-----+
|        type|class|
+------------+-----+
|Empty String|    0|
|Empty String|    0|
+------------+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This solves the issue I ran into today. I wonder if there is any way to replace an empty string in multiple columns at once